# Android adding header to listview in fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am adding a drawable image as header in listview. I have implemented it as follows in case of an activity.

```
listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);
```

However, now i am trying to implement the same in a viewpager fragment like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ShowFrag1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container,false);
        ListView lv1=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Level weather_data[] = new Level[]
                {
                    new Level(R.drawable.s1, "L1", R.drawable.p),
                    new Level(R.drawable.s2, "L2",R.drawable.p),
                    new Level(R.drawable.s3, "L3",R.drawable.p),
                    new Level(R.drawable.s4, "L4",R.drawable.p),
                    new Level(R.drawable.s6, "L5",R.drawable.p)
                };
        LevelAdapter adapter = new LevelAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item, weather_data);

       View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        lv1.addHeaderView(header);

        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now in this, i am getting an error "

> The method getLayoutInflater(Bundle) in the type Fragment is not
>   applicable for the arguments ()

" in the line

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
```

How do i resolve this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
```

with

```
  View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
```

the first paramter of `onCreatView` is a `LayoutInflater`

Comment: yes of course. That's depends on how did you wrote R.layout.header